# How do you fix a mispelled tag?

Tags: support, tagging

The [cultural-awarness](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cultural-awarness) tag is missing an `e`.

Is that something a high rep user (like me) can fix?
 If so, how?

Comment: How do you fix a misspelling of /misspelled/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of an A that might be accepted, copy of a Comment from a mod:

> We create a new tag, set the misspelled one to a synonym, then do a merge - which will remove the old tag. (I'll do that from my computer.)
>    – Ankur Banerjee♦ Jan 1 '15 at 6:24

The adjustment has been made.

Answer (score 4):

Good question. Now you *could* just edit the twenty questions using it and delete the current misspelled tag and add the correctly spelled tag.

(That wouldn't work with regular plurals or hyphenated vs non-hyphenated, but works in all other cases.)

The drawback is that it has a tag wiki and those have histories of who made what edit to them at what time. Copying the current tag wiki over will erase that history and credit you as the sole tag editor.

Worse is that there are badges awarded to creators of tags when they get enough use. You would also become the new creator of the tag and the old creator will never be able to get those badges.

So I'm hoping there's a less damaging way to do it and you can accept that as the answer and not this one! (-:

Comment: We create a new tag, set the misspelled one to a synonym, then do a merge - which will remove the old tag. (I'll do that from my computer.)

Comment: Update: this is now done